# Adaptive card column style is working in Adaptive Designer but not in WebChat

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm using Adaptive Card version 1.2 and I'm trying to add style for Adaptive Column. The style is getting reflected in Adaptive Designer(Web Chat). But the same if I try to check in hosted Web Chat styles are not getting reflected. Also I would like to mention that I'm creating Adaptive card using C#.

[image: Required Result]

But it is looking like this
[image: Current Result]

The i'm using this for webchat (https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js)

Here is my C# code

```
AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard(new AdaptiveSchemaVersion(1, 0));
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
{
    Text = $"Hello User",
    HorizontalAlignment = AdaptiveHorizontalAlignment.Center
});
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
{
    FontType = AdaptiveFontType.Monospace,
    Text = "Would you like to rate us",
    Color = AdaptiveTextColor.Good,
    Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
    HorizontalAlignment = AdaptiveHorizontalAlignment.Center,
    Separator = true
}); 
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveColumnSet()
{
    Separator = true,
    Columns = new List<AdaptiveColumn>()
        {
            new AdaptiveColumn()
            {
            Bleed = true,
            Width = AdaptiveColumnWidth.Stretch,
            Style = AdaptiveContainerStyle.Emphasis,
             SelectAction = new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
            {
                Title = "1",
                DataJson = "{ \"Type\": \"1\" }"
            },
            Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
            {
                new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                {
                    Text = "1",
                }
            }
        },
            new AdaptiveColumn()
        {
            Bleed = true,
            Width = AdaptiveColumnWidth.Stretch,
            Style = AdaptiveContainerStyle.Accent,
             SelectAction = new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
            {
                Title = "2",
                DataJson = "{ \"Type\": \"2\" }"
            },
            Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
            {
                new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                {
                    Text = $"2"
                }
            }
        },
            new AdaptiveColumn()
        {
            Bleed = true,
            Width = AdaptiveColumnWidth.Stretch,
            Style = AdaptiveContainerStyle.Good,
            SelectAction = new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
            {
                Title = "3",
                DataJson = "{ \"Type\": \"3\" }"
            },
            Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
            {
                new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                {
                    Text = $"3"
                }
            }
        },
            new AdaptiveColumn()
            {
            Bleed = true,
            Width = AdaptiveColumnWidth.Stretch,
            Style = AdaptiveContainerStyle.Attention,
            SelectAction = new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
            {
                Title = "4",
                DataJson = "{ \"Type\": \"4\" }"
            },
            Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
            {
                new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                {
                    Text = $"4"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please help me on this

Comment: This issue will be fixed in the next version of Web Chat - v4.8.0 - which should be release sometime in March. Take a look at this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2772) for more details.

Comment: @tdurnford I have a similar issue I posted on Github on that issue. The feedback there helped but I still haven't quite been able to get the formatting correct. Wondering if there are some additional format settings I can change.

Comment: @billoverton I'd recommend opening another StackOverflow question